# Interpret high p and q orders of GARCH models

Tags: time-series, interpretation, model-selection, garch, lags

I am currently working with GARCH models (sGARCH, E-GARCH and GJR-GARCH). My question is very general. I chose my p and q orders with the help of AIC criterion. The best models are sGARCH(2,3),
E-GARCH(3,3) and GJR-GARCH(3,2). I have some issues interpreting the high amount of parameters/high orders. How could one interpret the need for 2 gamma parameters for the E-GARCH(3,3) model for example? Or even for the standard GARCH. Whats the implication of a GARCH order q of 3?

I hope the question makes sense.

Thank you!